# How to prevent TypeScript from interrupting Webpack building on unresolved variables declared on Webpack's ProvidePlugin?

Tags: typescript, webpack, tsconfig, webpack-plugin

Is there a way to prevent WebPack's building process from failing after typescript compiler start yelling on unresolved variables that actually are already configured on webpack's ProvidePlugin configuration?

**webpack.config.js**

```
plugins: [
...
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery",
            "window.jQuery": "jquery",
            "_": "underscore",
            "underscore": "underscore"
            //'process.env.NODE_ENV': '"development"'
        }),

]
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {


    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "declaration": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#provideplugin

From my experience, the typescript is not aware of which variables will be injected into the module and as result the build is not completed.

**This is the output of the build**

```
ERROR in ./src/file1.component.ts
(77,9): error TS2304: Cannot find name '$'.

ERROR in ./src/file2.component.ts
(78,13): error TS2304: Cannot find name '$'.

ERROR in ./src/file3.ts
(155,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'jQuery'.

ERROR in ./src/file4.ts
(108,9): error TS2304: Cannot find name '$'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand ProvidePlugin correctly you still need to have declared jQuery and underscore as modules (externals or alias).

Therefore I'd recommend to load those modules in TypeScript with:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import * as _ from 'underscore';
```

Then you just need to provide definition (.d.ts) files for those libraries. I recommend [typings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typings) for that purpose.

```
typings install jquery --global
typings install underscore --global
```

I assume you are using [ts-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-loader) which would handle that automatically.

If you want to avoid `import` statements you can still declare those libraries with definitions from typings.

Or you can create your own simplified declaration:

```
declare var jQuery: any;
declare var $: any;
```

Answer (score 7):

I'm not fully satisfied with ahz's answer as I don't like to install typings globally or declare `jQuery` as `any` loosing all typechecking.

The solution that worked for me is to create **global.d.ts** with following content:

```
import * as _jQuery from 'jquery';

declare global {
  const jQuery: typeof _jQuery;
  const $: typeof _jQuery;
}
```

After that `tsc` passes without any warnings like `Cannot find name '$'.`.

Found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3180#issuecomment-283089923).

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna add to the top answer, by saying there's some exceptions, and here's how to solve them. I ran with this problem using Ant-Design and Redux.

When you use this:

```js
import _Fake from 'fake-lib'

declare global {
  const Fake: typeof _Fake
}
```

It works, but only for libraries that have been exported as a namespace (Like React). In this case, you can safely do this:

```js
const x: Fake.Property // GOOD: Fake acts as a namespace
Fact.Function          // GOOD: Fake acts a concrete type that contains Function
```

On the other hand, I had libraries that did not export as namespace (Like Redux) and caused this:

```js
const x: Fake.Property // FAIL: Fake is not a namespace
Fact.Function          // GOOD: Fake acts a concrete type that contains Function
```

To circumvent this issue, you can essentially globally-augment the library to be treated as a namespace export, like so:

Modify your tsconfig.json to add the new hacks

```json
"compilerOptions": {
    ...
},
"include": [
    "./src/**/*",
    "./types/**/*"
]
```

And add a `types/fake.d.ts` file containing

```js
import * as Fake from 'fake-library'

export as namespace Fake
export = Fake
```

With these changes done now the global const declaration will work properly.

Answer (score -1):

Don't `babel-loader` with `ts-loader`(remove this one!) upon babel 7! I hope this will save someone debugging in the future! [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52323181/5290519)