# How to setup TypeScript + Babel + Webpack?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, babeljs

I have these dependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/node": "^4.0.27-alpha",
  "babel-core": "^6.10.4",
  "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
  "babel-polyfill": "^6.9.1",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
  "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
  "ts-loader": "^0.8.2",
  "typescript": "^2.0.0",
  "webpack": "^1.13.1"
}
```

.babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "stage-0"
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "sourceMap": false,
        "outDir": "built"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/'],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: './built/bundle.js',
  },
  resolve: {
    modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'],
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts'],
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.tsx?$/, loaders: ['ts-loader', 'babel-loader'], exclude: /node_modules/
    }],
  }
};
```

/src/index.ts:

```
async function foo() {
  const value = await bar();
  console.log(value);
}

function bar() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return resolve(4);
  });
}

(async function run() {
  await foo();
}());
```

With this setup it does work, I can build and run it (logs 4 correctly). However I'm always getting some errors on Webpack:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.ts
(4,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'regeneratorRuntime'.

ERROR in ./src/index.ts
(6,12): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'regeneratorRuntime'.

ERROR in ./src/index.ts
(31,451): error TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

ERROR in ./src/index.ts
(40,33): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'regeneratorRuntime'.

ERROR in ./src/index.ts
(41,12): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'regeneratorRuntime'.
```

It seems it has something to do with `babel-polyfill`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> (4,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'regeneratorRuntime'.

This is a symptom that the output of `babel` is getting fed to `ts`. This order is **wrong**

## Fix

You compilation setup should have TS output fed to Babel.

Alternatively you can compile TypeScript with just Babel using `@babel/preset-typescript`.

## More

Compiling TypeScript with Babel : https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-typescript

Comment: Fixes should avoid linking to external sites which fragments the information. Instead, consider providing the same idea in your answer.

Answer (score 109):

#### Babel 7 does not need ts-loader.

As of Babel 7 the `ts-loader` is unnecessary, because [Babel 7 understands TypeScript](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2018/08/27/typescript-and-babel-7/). Complete details of a [TypeScript + Babel7 + Webpack setup are here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Babel-Starter).

#### An overview of the set up without ts-loader.

Install Babel's TypeScript support. Only `@babel/preset-typescript` is mandatory; the other three add additional features that TypeScript supports.

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-typescript 
npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-env 
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties 
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread
```

Configure the additional `.babelrc` plugins and presets.

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-typescript"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/proposal-class-properties",
        "@babel/proposal-object-rest-spread"
    ]
}
```

And update your `webpack.config.js` (other code is omitted for clarity).

```
module: {
  rules: [
  {
     test: /\.(js|jsx|tsx|ts)$/,
     exclude: /node_modules/,
     loader: 'babel-loader'
    }
  ]
},
resolve: {
  extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx', '.tsx', '.ts'],
},
```

Comment: Is it necessary to repeat presets configuration in webpack file? Isn't specyfying them in babelrc enough?

Comment: This is the right answer^ with the move to babel@7.

Comment: One difference between `ts-loader` and using Babel 7 with `babel-loader` is that `ts-loader` type-checks during transpilation; babel-loader does not. The instructions for using TypeScript with Babel 7 linked in this answer suggest calling `tsc` separately to type-check.

Comment: How about the namespaces ?? they are not supported

Comment: ts-loader also have additional option like custom tsconfig path. It should not be advised to use babel-loader instead of ts-loader (at least now in 2020)

Comment: @EricBurel: I'm against your point. `ts-loader` is not required in using babel. This is the point. Either Babel itself or tsc itself will come to a state where no plugin is required to achieve the same result. Advising people to rely on community-maintained plugin is usually not future proof. FYI: I don't use `ts-loader`, since I don't need those features. I want stability.

Comment: It doesn't __need__ ts-loader, but you should use it with Babel.

Answer (score 46):

Loaders always execute right to left, so changing to

```
test: /\.tsx?$/, loaders: ['babel-loader', 'ts-loader'], exclude: /node_modules/
```

fixed the issue since it is going to run `ts-loader` first.

Full webpack.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/'],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: './dist/index.js',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts'],
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.ts$/, loaders: ['babel-loader', 'ts-loader'], exclude: /node_modules/
    }],
  }
};
```

Sample project: [brunolm/typescript-babel-webpack](https://github.com/brunolm/typescript-babel-webpack).

Answer (score 7):

This thread is a little dated...
If you want to use **babel** together **with ts-loader** in 2023:

##### Install

```
npm install -D babel-loader @babel/core @babel/preset-env
```

##### Webpack loaders configuration

```
{
  entry: './src/index.tsx',
  // ... your other webpack configs
  module: {
    // ... your other module configs
    rules: [
      // ... your other rolues configs
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: [
                ['@babel/preset-env', { targets: 'defaults' }],
              ],
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            options: {
              transpileOnly: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

Tested with my *electron-forge* setup.
(Running **NodeJS 19.0.0** with **TypeScript 5.0.2**, **@babel/core 7.21.3**, **babel-loader 9.1.2** and **ts-loader 9.2.2**)

Comment: the `transpileOnly` option of ts-loader should only be true in dev mode tho, you still need to type check when building