# Do I need babel-loader on top of tsloader to transpile typescript with webpack?

Tags: typescript, webpack, babel-loader, ts-loader

I am writing `webpack.config.js` to transpile typescript (to be more precise tsx) into ES5 using `tsloader` and `babel-loader`.
I have two questions:

1) Do we still need `babel-loader` even though `tsloader` output ES5 files?
2) Does it make sense to set `compilerOptions.module` in `tsconfig.json` to `es6` when the target is `es5`?

`tsconfig.json` is as follows:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react"
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1) Do we still need babel-loader even though tsloader output ES5 files?

No, we don't, unless there's a need to use non-compliant features that aren't supported by TypeScript (usually there's none).

> 2) Does it make sense to set compilerOptions.module in tsconfig.json to es6 when the target is es5?

Yes. It outputs ES5 code with ES modules that can be processed by bundling system (Webpack or Rollup).

Comment: thanks! Does it make any difference to webpack when compilerOptions.module is commonjs?

Comment: Of course. The most important difference is that ES modules support tree-shaking. You import only what you use (this may vary depending on third-party packages).

Comment: The first part of your answer is no longer valid(and should be updated): Upon Babel v7, only `babel-loader` is needed since it can read TypeScript.

Comment: @Rainning It's true but depends on the intention. It won't check types because it's... Babel, and there are some other differences https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-typescript#caveats

Comment: OK, my statement is baed on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52323181/5290519, sorry if that I might misunderstood it. Btw, I have a lot of confusion now. Could you help with my question related to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71756885/webpack-tree-shaking-setup-among-webpack-babel-loader-typescript-tsconfig-targe

Comment: @Rainning The question's good, can't help with tree shaking though for the most part

Comment: @EstusFlask: Might I ask you an additional question(, which is somehow important to me)? If the editor I'm using has `tsserver` language-server, does this mean that I actually don't need the cross-file type-checking feature from `ts-loader`(or anything similar)?

Comment: @Rainning It depends on your ide setup. But generally you'll be able to see errors in specific files in IDE, while the entire code base needs to be checked to guarantee that everything's ok. This kind of problem didn't occur to me, but if you ditch ts loader because of performance issues, you could keep type checking separated, e.g. build:check command, while keeping dev server and build are as fast as possible