# Webpack Tree-Shaking Setup among Webpack babel-loader, TypeScript tsconfig target, @babel/preset-env modules: false, package.json side-effects:false?

Tags: typescript, webpack, babel-loader, webpack-5

As title. This is the longer version:

1. My target is to setup the tree-shaking feature of Webpack (for es6-modules, or ESM, `.ejs` if you prefer).
2. My confusion is among these configs: Webpack v5 with `babel-loader`(, which can be tuned from `webpack.*.config.js`) + Babel v7 with preset `@babel/preset-env`(, which can be tuned from `babel.config.js`) + TypeScript, which can be tuned from `tsconfig.json`. Details follow:

   - First, from `tsconfig.json`, I noticed that I don't understand whether the `"target": "es5"` should be changed to `"target": "es6"`, or whether this may not matter at all. This is my reasoning:

     > Even if the target set to "es6", the `babel-loader` will (probably) further transpile it to "es5" according to the `"browserslist"` field I have setup in the `package.json`. And for webpack tree-shaking to work, I *guess* that I should not transpile my code to "es5" too early.

     But this argument  is based on the fact that `babel-loader` will only read `"browserslist"`, and don't give it a _ to `tsconfig.json`. Please correct me if anything is wrong.
   - Second, let's talk about babel. Inside the `babel.config.js` there is an option `modules: false`, which is apparently needed to command Babel not to transpile the ESM import so that tree-shaking will work. So this provides more context for the first question above: If I set `modules: false`, then it should mean that the input of `babel-loader`, i.e. the `.js` from `.tsx` according to `tsconfig.json`, should not transpile ESM import too. Please correct me if anything is wrong.
   - Finally, about `package.json` and `webpack.*.config.js`. The option `sideEffects: false` is required for tree-shaking to work. But it seems that the this option can be added from both `package.json`(then should be the form `"side-effects"`) and `webpack.*.config.js`'s `sideEffects` field for `babel-loader`. I actually haven't tested which will work. Any advice on choosing the two options here?

There is one more context that I only use `babel-loader`, no `ts-loader` (actually I'm not sure about whether this is correct). This is based on [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52323181/5290519) from this forum, and it is the only way that works for me when I was solving another problem. If `ts-loader` is needed for this problem, please let me know, thank again.

Comment: I suppose at least some confusion comes from es5/es6 choice. Notice that there's such thing as ES5 with ESM that's primarily suited to be used with bundlers. `Even if the target set to "es6", the babel-loader will (probably) further transpile it to "es5"` - in case you're after es5 target regardless of browserslist, this is primarily a choice between TS and Babel ES6 transforms. They are implemented differently, and Babel's are generally more convoluted but spec-compliant (although all nasty bugs that occurred to me during transpilation was from Babel, while TS output was generally smooth).

Comment: @EstusFlask: Thanks for the info. IIRC, I read a post claiming that Babel would do a better job for transpiling, and one another post saying that one should be aware that Babel would not do cross-file (i.e. it doesn't have the concept of "project") type-checking and thus dangerous to use alone. This let me want to ask "how to have both"? Anyway, so many unsolved questions now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My target is to setup the tree-shaking feature [...]

Upon webpack 5, it's enabled by default **in production mode** already. But you do need to keep ESM syntax to make it works. If you want to enable it in development mode, add `usedExports: true`.

> [...] TypeScript, which can be tuned from **tsconfig.json**.
>
> [...] or whether this may not matter at all.

If you don't use something like `ts-loader` then the answer is (an absolute) **Yes**, since babel doesn't use it to decide tranpilation target.

> [...] should mean that the input of babel-loader, i.e. the `.js` from `.tsx` according to `tsconfig.json`, should not transpile ESM import too.

Correct.

> [...] The option `sideEffects: false` is required for tree-shaking to work.

Incorrect.

> [...] Any advice on choosing the two options here?

Pick package.json one. You probably read too many posts on StackOverflow where someone used an *imaginary* syntax.

> [...] I only use `babel-loader`, no `ts-loader` (actually I'm not sure about **whether this is correct**)

You can. And it's appropriate in your case, since you have `tsserver` on your god-dame neovim, which already does the cross-file type-checking for you. But still you should find some time to try it. A lot of optimizations seem to be done by them.